# Default values for Laravel 5.4+ blades new components?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Laravel 5.4+ allows for components of the following structure:

```
<div class="alert alert-{{ $type }}">
    <div class="alert-title">{{ $title }}</div>
    {{ $slot }}
</div>
```

Which are called like:

```
@component('alert', ['type' => 'danger'])
    @slot('title') 
        oh no 
    @endslot
    Foo
@endcomponent
```

Is there a shorthand or blade marker to set default values for the variables passed in?

For example, in the above, if I don't pass in "type" I get a `undefined variable` error. I could do something like:

```
<div class="alert alert-{{ isset($type) ? $type : 'default' }}">
```

But the above feels verbose, especially if the variable is used in multiple spots.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think it does.

Having said that blade has the `or` operator that wraps the `isset()` call ([see docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data)).

```
<div class="alert alert-{{ $type or 'default' }}">
```

If you're running php 7 this is a case for the [Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php).

```
<div class="alert alert-{{ $type ?? 'default' }}">
```

Both will make your call site tider.

Comment: Yeah nice, I like it. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In your php file related to your component, set a default value for your parameters:

```
public function __construct($type = 'text')
{
    $this->type = $type;
}
```

That's it.

This has worked for me in laravel 8